# postgres function that returns random enum

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to write a function `random_enum(enum_name)` that returns random enum value

I have stopped on this variant

```
create type  myenum
as enum (
   'one',
   'two',
   'three',
   'four'
);


create or replace function random_enum(relation_name anyelement) returns anyenum as $$
begin
  return execute format(
    $sql$
      select unnest(enum_range(NULL::%1$I)) ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
    $sql$,
    pg_typeof(relation_name)
  );
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select random_enum(null::myenum)
```

[you can try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ed36f4fb12c4da788c716210131e997a)

but it doesn't work because of

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 12:   return execute format(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an out parameter in the way:

```
create or replace function random_enum(relation_name anyelement, out result anyenum) 
as $$
begin
  execute format(
    $sql$
      select elem 
      from unnest(enum_range(null::%1$I)) as elem
      order by random() 
      limit 1;
    $sql$,
    pg_typeof(relation_name)
  ) into result;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

[db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1aa547366627071a228fb5ee7b65c699)

Comment: I've removed redundant elements of the function and added a comment in db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative without OUT parameter and defined as SQL function.

```
create or replace function random_enum(
                  relation_name_in  text
                ) 
          returns text 
         language sql strict
as $$
    select e.enumlabel::text
      from pg_type t 
      join pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
      join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = t.typnamespace
     where t.typname = lower(relation_name_in)
     order by random()
     limit 1;
$$ ;

-- test 
select soq.random_enum('myenum');
```

Comment: tnx, this solution is working https://pastebin.com/pfGFDsfm 
, but I need to convert text type to desired enum type, whereas with @klin solution I specify desired enum type only once https://pastebin.com/TvRpq3E0